# SlidingPaneLayout - Animate similar to Android Hangouts app

Tags: android, animation, layouttransition, slidingpanelayout

I have implemented a SlidingPaneLayout with fragments that looks like this (summarizing)

```
<SlidingPaneLayout
    android:xmlns="...."
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


    <ListView />
    <FrameLayout />
</SlidingPaneLayout>
```

So the ListView is the "slide out" pane. It all works fine and exactly as I expect it to.

However, I'm interested in achieving the animate affect (where the ListView would come in from the left as the pane is pulled out, following the touch)

I've tried making a slide_in_left anim resource and setting it as a LayoutTransition, however this doesn't behave like I want it to. Guessing I need to do something with onPaneSlide?

Just wondering if there's a good way to implement this with SlidingPaneLayout, thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)

Comment: I'm aware of the Navigation Drawer, but that's a different pattern entirely than what I'm going for and what the hangouts app uses.

Comment: I would start by using **`uiautomatorviewer`** to determine if this is really `SlidingPaneLayout` in the first place.

Comment: That is a good suggestion, no mention of SlidingPaneLayout though, but also none in my app either. Looks like it actually renders/builds as a FrameLayout (as that appears to be the immediate level above the ListView/FrameLayout).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow it's too easy I just overlooked it big time.

SlidingPaneLayout has a method, setParallaxDistance, which adds the effect I was referring to.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html#setParallaxDistance(int)

Comment: if you wish to have the same using a navigation drawer, you can try out this library: https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer